# How to show link columns with datatables?

Tags: jslink, datatable

Is there a way to display link columns in a database table. I was following [this](https://yuriburger.net/2015/02/17/jslink-and-datatables/)  but turns out link fields aren't display with a link.

Instead the entire hyperlink is displayed which messes up the look and feel of the table. I added  following to the `DataTableListView.js` but it did not make any changes

```
else if (ctx.ListSchema.Field[index].Name === "Find_this_Opportunity") {
    cell = "<a href='" + ctx.displayFormUrl + "&ID=" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID +  "'>";
    cell += ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.ListSchema.Field[index].RealFieldName];
    cell += "</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. Here is the code that works.

```
    else if (ctx.ListSchema.Field[index].Name === "Find_this_Opportunity") {
        var OpportunityUrl = ctx.CurrentItem["Find_this_Opportunity"]
        var OpportunityDesc = ctx.CurrentItem["Find_this_Opportunity.desc"]         
        cell = '<a href="'+OpportunityUrl+'">'+OpportunityDesc+'</a>';
    }
```